# Azure devops pipeline for AKS Kubectl task failing to deploying manifest into AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-aks

kubectl task failing to deploying manifest files into AKS. pipeline failing with below error

**##[error]No configuration file matching /home/vsts/work/1/s/manifests was found.**

pipeline is working fine with run both stages (Like Build and Deploy) because after build stage it will create the artifacts for that manifest files and it will download in deploy stage and deploy in to AKS..

I have issue occur if I select stages to run only for deploy stage it will fail with above error msg..

Pipeline

```
- master

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'
  imagePullSecret: 'aks-acr-auth'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build image
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build And Push Into ACR
      inputs:
        containerRegistry: 'AKS-ACR'
        repository: 'apps/web'
        command: 'buildAndPush'
        Dockerfile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/app/Dockerfile'
        tags: |
          $(tag)

    - publish: manifests
      artifact: manifests
        
- stage: 'Deployment'
  displayName: 'Deploy To AKS'
  jobs:
    - deployment: Release
      environment: 'DEV-AKS.default'
      displayName: 'Release'
      pool:
        vmImage: ubuntu-latest
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:

            - task: KubernetesManifest@0
              displayName: Create imagePullSecret
              inputs:
                action: 'createSecret'
                kubernetesServiceConnection: 'DEV-AKS'
                secretType: 'dockerRegistry'
                secretName: '$(imagePullSecret)'
                dockerRegistryEndpoint: 'AKS-ACR'

            - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
              inputs:
                buildType: 'current'
                artifactName: 'manifests'
                targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'

            - task: Kubernetes@1
              displayName: Deploying Manifests into AKS
              inputs:
                connectionType: 'Kubernetes Service Connection'
                kubernetesServiceEndpoint: 'DEV-AKS'
                namespace: 'default'
                command: 'apply'
                useConfigurationFile: true
                configuration: 'manifests'
                secretType: 'dockerRegistry'
                containerRegistryType: 'Azure Container Registry'
```

Comment: It is because the artifact task is looking for the manifest artifact to download, but because you did not run build it won't work.
What you may want to do is apply a condition to the  task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2 
If you set a condition to the artifact download task based off build execution that will solve the problem ( partially... you are still calling the artifact in the deploy manifest into aks task) here is a link on conditions [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

Comment: Thanks @DaniloPatrucco, what will be the scenario if I have only deployment stage. like directly deploy into AKS without build stage.. Because we don't want for some service to customized image we need to directly deploying in to AKS.. I tired above pipeline without build stage and I removed the DownloadPipelineArtifact@2 task in to deployment stage. But still having same error msg...

Comment: try deleting this: configuration: 'manifests' from the task: Kubernetes@1 and see if that solves the issue, or at least it creates a new one

Comment: If I delete configuration: 'manifests' from the task: Kubernetes@1. then how will be manifest files deploy into AKS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Kasun comment I added -checkout: self and $(Build.SourcesDirectory) in pipeline it's works..

Pipeline

```
- master

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  imagePullSecret: 'acr-auth'

stages:
        
- stage: 'Deployment'
  displayName: 'Deploy To AKS'
  jobs:
    - deployment: Release
      environment: 'DEV-AKS.default'
      displayName: 'Release'
      pool:
        vmImage: ubuntu-latest
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
            - checkout: self

            - task: KubernetesManifest@0
              displayName: Create imagePullSecret
              inputs:
                action: 'createSecret'
                kubernetesServiceConnection: 'DEV-AKS'
                secretType: 'dockerRegistry'
                secretName: '$(imagePullSecret)'
                dockerRegistryEndpoint: 'AKS-ACR'

            - script: dir $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/manifests
              displayName: Cloning Manifest Files From Repo
              
            - task: KubernetesManifest@0
              displayName: Deploying Manifests InTo AKS
              inputs:
                action: 'deploy'
                kubernetesServiceConnection: 'DEV-AKS'
                namespace: 'default'
                manifests: |
                  manifests/deployment.yml
                  manifests/service.yml
                imagePullSecrets: '$(imagePullSecret)'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- master

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'
  imagePullSecret: 'aks-acr-auth'

- stage: 'Deployment'
  displayName: 'Deploy To AKS'
  jobs:
    - deployment: Release
      environment: 'DEV-AKS.default'
      displayName: 'Release'
      pool:
        vmImage: ubuntu-latest
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:

            - checkout: self
            - task: KubernetesManifest@0
              displayName: Create imagePullSecret
              inputs:
                action: 'createSecret'
                kubernetesServiceConnection: 'DEV-AKS'
                secretType: 'dockerRegistry'
                secretName: '$(imagePullSecret)'
                dockerRegistryEndpoint: 'AKS-ACR'

            - task: Kubernetes@1
              displayName: Deploying Manifests into AKS
              inputs:
                connectionType: 'Kubernetes Service Connection'
                kubernetesServiceEndpoint: 'DEV-AKS'
                namespace: 'default'
                command: 'apply'
                useConfigurationFile: true
                configuration: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/manifests'
                secretType: 'dockerRegistry'
                containerRegistryType: 'Azure Container Registry'
```

Can you check with the above pipeline yaml. Change the location artifact is downloaded and added the Build.SourcesDirectory as the path to download the artifacts

Comment: Thanks @kasun, Actually I need to run the pipeline without build stage so above scenario pipeline will try to download the artifact from build stage. but if didn't run the build stage artifact will not create. so it's failing with below msg.. 

Download from the specified build: #520143
Download artifact to: /home/vsts/work/1/s
##[error]Artifact manifests was not found for build 520143.
Finishing: DownloadPipelineArtifact

Comment: - checkout: self tag to clone the repo to this stage then you can use $(Build.SourcesDirectory) variable refer to the folder the code checkout, try this. This has to be work

Comment: Can you make this as an answer so others can know it works

Comment: yeah sure I will